# 'River of news' code sample in ruby?

Tags: ruby, feed

Looking for a good example of a 'River of News' implementation done in Ruby. Rails, merb, sinatra or any other web framework would work. I have a couple ideas about how to implement it, but would love to see how people would do it.

The implementation should load more items into the same page as soon the user reach the bottom of the document.

For more information about the 'River of News' format, please check [this video about humanized reader at vimeo](http://vimeo.com/89598).

Answer (score 1):

I know about [Mars](http://github.com/rubys/mars/tree/master), a river-of-news aggregator written by Sam Ruby as a port of Venus (which is written in Python and is a refactoring of Planet). Please note that, however, it doesn't use a web framework; if this is a strict requirement on your part, then Mars may not be what you need.

Venus, the aggregator which the Mars port has originated from, comes with [extensive documentation](http://intertwingly.net/code/venus/docs/index.html): some (most?) of it should probably be valid for Mars, too; you may be particularly interested in the [architectural diagram](http://intertwingly.net/code/venus/docs/venus.svg) of the software.

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't clear in my question. I want to see how people do the 'river of news' updating method where more items are loaded when the user reach the end of the page. I've updated the question tor reflect this.